# Axios error request failed with 401 React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios

I have a useEffect function that calls an api by axios with some bearer authentication in it. Here is my code

```
const user = useContext(UserContext )

const taskGetFunc = async () => {
    try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://demo.shikkhaapp.com/api/homework-list/1',
    
      headers: {'Authorization': user.token}
    })
    console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(user.token)
      console.log(error)  

    }
    
    
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    taskGetFunc()
  }, [])
```

now this returns me this error

```
Request failed with status code 401
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:57:6 in onloadend
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:614:6 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

I know this is an error regarding authentication, but I tried the `user.token` in the postman and in reqbin. it works perfectly there but not on my react app. I tried doing it in fetch, different ways in axios, but shows me the same error.

Could you please help me with any idea, what might cause the error.

The user.token is a string with Bearer token.

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMGNmNTFiMzQ5ZDliZTVjYjVjODVhOTUzOTk0ZGUzMTY2MDA3Nzk4Njk3MjNkOWRlYTAyOWRjZTgzY2U3N2E3OTJjOTA3Y2RhMmQyMDMzMTQiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDU5MDYxNDguNjkwNTEyODk1NTg0MTA2NDQ1MzEyNSwibmJmIjoxNjQ1OTA2MTQ4LjY5MDUxNTA0MTM1MTMxODM1OTM3NSwiZXhwIjoxNjc3NDQyMTQ4LjY4OTI5NzkxNDUwNTAwNDg4MjgxMjUsInN1YiI6IjQyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.LfbwfLwO-PAAxhLcNLMXXelefcK6fmtKvFk55V2tRjWzP-XDqTUdkLO105ybkc1vU1QfX0gxdrCj4OSExItS82ySG5-mD4JmrGk4ckN0Ffs581anL2l3zYuH_ExulG564-Jkbzkqsfbu4nR8ysmlbvBZZmn0B2elIlZWnZRp-5XkDJkUTpvJKrl4CPoc4mldX_5VnoYaoob4ctHkNNVw4FBdnXRXX-OzzpmeW6D9aey1KZcHcwg6OE0aiA5wmp1YwC3Ou2lVE6XbUOl1e0VAFKOCJcCF3i29k89JEnFVuKW-X9tcajFbjRf1UohdpkY-uoIini1256ky-BN3C_98Gqq3w-CORLhbdfQIqET9kzilnKE7pJ97oXHUGzIJSu--IPMfljI9wHfFugXqsBzwa0fD8I1zg9uYW_oNtA264sVdgqVbntp23Q6KG9tecJCBPl7QToVsxaLx9hWjWuos39bt3nyp4Zj4iu4m3X4tGQpTZ-ZOsiY0UD1lGC5CclDTO1LYM2mKX6qGULBlhStQqrzsd9IRC-Qsxxt-MBDN5OQVvKsefdp--c38QUQNHkrwYY6JyWv1umiXcYs0ejwmGUwOIP9657xwm_thHeFIppoeiGZYLO1dJaibSeuA1XLO_Jh7WZ6hg0aTaglIsxBfFf5pguMVNbZ60mQe5NIvclw
```

Here is the server side header, this is a php code because the server is made with laravel

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://demo.shikkhaapp.com/api/homework-list/1',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$bearerToken
  ),
));
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging user.token before sending the request, like before calling taskGetFunc? Just to be sure it is not being set after/during the request and before your actual console.log.

Comment: @jamomani I just did. It consoles log the proper token

Comment: And on the server side? Sorry, these are just basic advices but sometime we might forget to check these things.

Comment: @jamomani What do I need to check on the server side? It is developed in laravel. and I tried both with hardcoded token and conosle loging user.token. but seems like I cant pass the authentication at all, weirdly works fine in other platforms

Comment: Have checked the headers of the GET request from dev tools network tab? How does the authorization header looks? Maybe you could add that to you question, it could help to find out the problem.

Comment: @jamomani i added the server side header

Comment: Maybe it's a cors issue. Check your network dev tool. Is there an option request?

Comment: Does `user.token` in your React app actually include the _"Bearer "_ prefix? It's also not clear why you have some PHP code making the same request. What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: That "server side header" is for an HTTP client - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php cURL is a client program; I don't think it has any server functions at all.

Comment: This really isn't making much sense. Your client-side app sends a request to `demo.shikkhaapp.com`. You also have some PHP code that sends an identical request. Where is your PHP code running? Why do you have two things making identical requests?

Comment: Yes I agree, it seems wierd. Anyway I was thinking that since the postman request seems to work and from the app does not work, in my opinion it might help if we could compare the two requests. You could update the question with the authorization header sent with postman and authorization header sent from the browser (use dev tools for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, It was just an CORS error which the backend developer didnt agree at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript request do not define Authorization as Bearer token,
you should defined header as:

```
headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`}
```

If request work with Postman, you can ask to Postman [generate client code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/) and compare with your wrote network request in React with axios.

Comment: Thank you so much, brother! I never knew before that Postman has the ability to generate client code. This is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the bearer token either in the laravel or in the user.token because your current token is looking something like this `Bearer Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9`

your token should contain only on Bearer key

Comment: We have no idea where `$bearerToken` is defined or what value is assigned to it

Comment: I am assuming he is getting the value outside the curl_setopt_array and using it, he specified that the user. token contains bearer with the token and also setting the bearer in the curl_setopt_array